# Response Lag in UITableView displaying JSON data

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

In my application I am parsing JSON data and then displaying that data in UITableView. The information is displayed in the table but the touch response is lagging really bad. I did some research and found out that it is recommended to implement asynchronous loading for the information and especially the image, but I could not find any relevant solutio that worked with my JSON application. I would appreciate some suggestions and comments of how to sort out this problem, here is the code:

jURL Definition www.website.com/info.json

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(jQueue, ^{

        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:

                        jURL];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)

                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];

    });

}



- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;

    NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization

                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions

                          error:&error];

    calRes = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"results"];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}



 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *calDict = [calRes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[calDict objectForKey:@"image"]];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    cell.textLabel.text = [calDict objectForKey:@"name"];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [calDict objectForKey:@"description"];    
    cell.imageView.image = imageLoad;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: the lag is given by the image download inside the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, take a look to [this project](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to download the image in an asynchronous way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the [AFNetworking library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for easy asynchronous image loading. You will need to include the library

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

Then use it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[calDict objectForKey:@"image"]]
    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

You also need to supply a placeholder image. I use a blank JPG of the size you will want the final image will be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SDWebImage from this link : https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
It is the simplest and fastest library for asynchronous image loading.
It also provides image caching.
You can just done the whole operations by simply calling this function:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:jURL
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your place holder here"]];
```

Just enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up, it will be good to cache the images locally using this very handy plugin by Jake Marsh: [JMImageCache](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache)

This way, the images will not need to be loaded from the URL the next time you boot the app.

Answer (score 1):

See, the lagging in cellforRowAtIndexPath is because of this

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[calDict objectForKey:@"image"]];

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

UIImage *imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

why don't you, use GCD for adding the image? Further more you can have your own NSCache to store the image so that every time the table reloads, the image can be directly loaded from the memory instead of firing the url.